# Using props state in another state with redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have 2 component called OTP and User
In User I receive input number and I need to show this number when press button  in OTP Component.
I use redux and receive all state but not in one state here is my code

Action.js

```
import {
    SET_USER, SET_USER_FAILURE, SET_USER_OTP_FAILURE, SET_USER_OTP_REQUEST, SET_USER_OTP_SUCCESS, SET_USER_REQUEST,
    SET_USER_SUCCESS,
} from "./Type";
import {Alert} from "react-native";
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';



export const setUserRequest =(user) => (dispatch,getState) => {
    console.log(user);
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/mobileWebViews/v1/sendOtp/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            mobile:user,
            password:user,
            type:'otp'
        })
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            if(responseJson.status.toString() === 'ok'){
                // this.global.mobile = mobile;
                //console.log(responseJson);
                setUserSuccess(responseJson)
                Alert.alert('پیامک ارسال شد');
                Actions.replace('OTP');
                // Actions.Login(this.props.user);
                // console.log(this.props.user)

            }else if(responseJson.status.toString() === 'fail') {
                setUserFailure(error);
                //Alert.alert(responseJson.message.toString());
            }else{
                setUserFailure(error);
               // Alert.alert(responseJson.message.toString());
               // console.log(responseJson.message)
            }

        })
        .catch(error => {
            //setUserFailure(error)
            Alert.alert("Error"+JSON.stringify(error));
            // console.error(error);
        })
    dispatch({
        type:SET_USER_REQUEST,
        user:user,
    })

}


export const setUserSuccess =(user)=>({
    type:SET_USER_SUCCESS,
    user:user,
});

export const setUserFailure =(user)=>({
    type:SET_USER_FAILURE,
    user:user,
    error:true,
});



export const setUserRequestOTP =(OTP) => (dispatch) => {
    console.log(OTP);
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/mobileWebViews/v1/Login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
           mobile:OTP,
            password:OTP,
            type:'Login'
        })
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            if(responseJson.status.toString() === 'ok'){
                // this.global.mobile = mobile;
                setUserSuccessOTP(responseJson)
                Alert.alert('پیامک ارسال شد');
                Actions.replace('OTP');
                UserData();

            }else if(responseJson.status.toString() === 'fail') {
                setUserFailureOTP(error);
               // Alert.alert(responseJson.message.toString());
            }else{
                setUserFailureOTP(error);
               // Alert.alert(responseJson.message.toString());
               // console.log(responseJson.message)
            }

        })
        .catch(error => {
            setUserFailureOTP(error)
            Alert.alert("Error"+JSON.stringify(error));
            // console.error(error);
        })
    dispatch({
        type:SET_USER_OTP_REQUEST,
        OTP:OTP,

    })
}

export const setUserSuccessOTP =(OTP)=>({
    type:SET_USER_OTP_SUCCESS,
    OTP:OTP,
});

export const setUserFailureOTP =(OTP)=>({
    type:SET_USER_OTP_FAILURE,
    OTP:OTP,
    error:true,
});
```

Type.js

```
export const SET_USER='SET_USER';
export const SET_USER_REQUEST='SET_USER_REQUEST';
export const SET_USER_SUCCESS='SET_USER_SUCCESS';
export const SET_USER_FAILURE='SET_USER_FAILURE';
export const SET_USER_OTP_REQUEST='SET_USER_OTP_REQUEST';
export const SET_USER_OTP_SUCCESS='SET_USER_OTP_SUCCESS';
export const SET_USER_OTP_FAILURE='SET_USER_OTP_FAILURE';
```

Reducers.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import user from './UserReducers';
import OTP from './UserReducers';
export default combineReducers({
    user,
    OTP,
})
```

UserReducers.js

```
import {SET_USER, SET_USER_OTP_SUCCESS, SET_USER_SUCCESS} from "../Actions/Type";

const initialState = {

    mobile:'',
    OTP:'',

}

export default  data =(state= initialState,action={}) =>{
    switch (action.type){
        case SET_USER_SUCCESS :
            const { user,OTP }=action;
            return {mobile:user.mobile}

        case SET_USER_OTP_SUCCESS:
            return {password:OTP.password}

            break;

        default:
            return state;

}
}
```

store.js

```
import {createStore,applyMiddleware, compose} from  'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import reducers from './../Reducers';

const middleware = [thunk];
middleware.push(createLogger());

const store= createStore(
    reducers,
    undefined,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),

    )
);

export default store;
```

Comment: @ Mohamad reza golbaba, create a mapStateToProps. With this you can get the state from OTP and convert it to props and show it in your scene. Can you put your scene javascript code too in which you want the OTP to be shown.

Comment: @jason im use mapStateToProps at end of OTP but its not work

Comment: show your code of mapStateProps maybe you are doing somehting wrong.